# Creating class object to do factorial recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I was assigned a problem to write a program using recursion, which is working properly, my only question is that it was specified to create a class object to do the factorial calculation instead of method...am I doing this right?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment2A {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //sets up scanner
        boolean correct = true;             //sets up boolean operation
        while(true){
            try{                                //try catch operation
                System.out.println("Welcome to the factorial function");
                System.out.println("Please enter a number or press 0 to exit");
                long startTime =System.nanoTime();
                System.out.println("Start Time: "+startTime+" nanoseconds."); //display the start time

                int n = scan.nextInt();             //scans the input
                int factorial= fact(n);             
                System.out.println("The Factorial of the number entered is: " + factorial);

                long taskTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+" nanoseconds.\n\n");

            }catch(Exception e){                //checks if the input is a string or character
                System.out.println("That is not a number!");    //displays that the input is invalid
                long startTime =System.nanoTime();
                long taskTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+" nanoseconds.");
                System.exit(0);         //exits the program
            }
        }
    }

    static int fact(int n){
        int output;                 //sets the output as int
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();     //gets the start time of the cpu
        long taskTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;    //gets the task time
        if (n==0){                      //if the input is 0, system exits
            System.out.println("Exiting Program");      
            System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+ " nanoseconds."); //displays cpu time
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(n==1){
            return 1;           //if input is 1, the factorial of 1 is 1
        }
        output = fact(n-1)*n;   //recursive method for factorial
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're writing a Java program then you're writing at least one class.  If you're to perform recursion in a Java program then you're certainly intended to do it via a method or methods.  I have not reviewed your code in detail, but you appear to be addressing the assignment in a reasonable way.

Comment: No. you are calculating a factorial using method fact. You may want to move your fact into a new class probably "Factorial.java", expose the method as public. and call new Factorial( number ).factorial();

Comment: Although the code above works by itself - recommended way to do it is create a separate class Factorial (with one static method "performFactorial") and another class that manages the user input and output messages (i.e. UserInteraction). Then create a driver class with the main() method, create necessary objects of these classes to do your work (i.e. use UserInteraction class to get the input, pass this to the Factorial class, and then display the output). The principle at work here is Separation of Concerns (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: @AndrasDeak `public class Assignment2A` is the answer. Original comment deleted, what a shame.

Comment: @AaronGillion yeah, sorry to be the bringer of bad news.

Answer (score 3):

No, you created a method, fact(int n) that calculates the factorial.

You should create a new class with a method that calculates the factorial. An object of the class would be instantiated and then, the method that calculates the factorial would be invoked from the class object.

Example:

```
// outside the while loop instantiate your class object for
// dealing with factorial computations
Factorial factorial = new Factorial();

// inside the while loop, instantiate your method for 
// computing factorial of "n", invoking your factorial 
// computation method that is defined inside your class
int result = factorial.computeFactorial(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a class object then remove static from your method
Also it would be better if you use dynamic programming approach for solving this problem.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment2A {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Assignment2A x = new Assignment2A();
        x.askForOutput();
    }

    int fact(int n){
        int output;                 //sets the output as int
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();     //gets the start time of the cpu
        long taskTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;    //gets the task time
        if (n==0){                      //if the input is 0, system exits
            System.out.println("Exiting Program");      
            System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+ " nanoseconds."); //displays cpu time
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(n==1){
            return 1;           //if input is 1, the factorial of 1 is 1
        }
        output = fact(n-1)*n;   //recursive method for factorial
        return output;

    }
    public void askForOutput(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //sets up scanner
        boolean correct = true;             //sets up boolean operation
        while(true){
            try{                                //try catch operation
                System.out.println("Welcome to the factorial function");
                System.out.println("Please enter a number or press 0 to exit");
                long startTime =System.nanoTime();
                System.out.println("Start Time: "+startTime+" nanoseconds."); //display the start time

                int n = scan.nextInt();             //scans the input
                int factorial= fact(n);             
                System.out.println("The Factorial of the number entered is: " + factorial);

                long taskTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+" nanoseconds.\n\n");

            }catch(Exception e){                //checks if the input is a string or character
                System.out.println("That is not a number!");    //displays that the input is invalid
                long startTime =System.nanoTime();
                long taskTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+" nanoseconds.");
                System.exit(0);         //exits the program
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How is this approach so dynamic?

Comment: I am suggesting to use a dynamic approach. this is not dynamic way of doing it. I just changed the code provided

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be in a separate class, just encapsulate your fact() method in a new class. Note, however, that your printout of the time taken is incorrect - it merely computes the time for the final entry into the recursive method.

```
public class Factorial {

   public static int compute( int val ) {
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();
      int result = fact( val );
      long taskTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
      System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+ " nanoseconds.");
   }

   protected static int fact( int val ) {
      if (n==1){
         return val;
      }
      return fact(val-1)*val;
   }
}
```

then in you main,

```
 int answer =  Factorial.compute(value);
```